# Using OpenXML in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, openxml

I have a table in which for some reason the rows are in XML format.

I have to parse those rows, and create a new table from the XML itself.

I read and found there is [OpenXML](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918(v=sql.110).aspx) for that in SQL Server. I am working with SQL Server 2016 SP1 version.

I follow the instructions on how to use the XML from the above link but:

```
DECLARE @idoc int, @doc varchar(1000);
```

> Command(s) completed successfully.

Next command:

```
SET @doc ='
<ROOT>
<Customer CustomerID="VINET" ContactName="Paul Henriot">
   <Order CustomerID="VINET" EmployeeID="5" OrderDate="1996-07-04T00:00:00">
      <OrderDetail OrderID="10248" ProductID="11" Quantity="12"/>
      <OrderDetail OrderID="10248" ProductID="42" Quantity="10"/>
   </Order>
</Customer>
<Customer CustomerID="LILAS" ContactName="Carlos Gonzlez">
   <Order CustomerID="LILAS" EmployeeID="3" OrderDate="1996-08-16T00:00:00">
      <OrderDetail OrderID="10283" ProductID="72" Quantity="3"/>
   </Order>
</Customer>
</ROOT>';
```

For this I get:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 1870
>    Must declare the scalar variable "@doc".

**Which is strange since I declared it successfully just in the above command.**

And now:

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc;
```

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1887
>    Must declare the scalar variable "@idoc".

Any way this error can be solved?

Comment: you should to run all of lines same time

Comment: @sarslan but in code, the lines will get executed one by one right... suppose I put all of this in a function or stored procedure...then ...could you help a bit if I want to put all of this as a procedure?

Comment: @RajeshRonaldo, correct the lines will run in a logical order but the whole script needs to be complied first, you are declaring a local variable which has a life span of the current batch, one its finished it will be 'removed'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running each part individually?

Run the whole thing as one script:

```
DECLARE @idoc int, @doc varchar(1000);
SET @doc ='
<ROOT>
<Customer CustomerID="VINET" ContactName="Paul Henriot">
   <Order CustomerID="VINET" EmployeeID="5" OrderDate="1996-07-04T00:00:00">
      <OrderDetail OrderID="10248" ProductID="11" Quantity="12"/>
      <OrderDetail OrderID="10248" ProductID="42" Quantity="10"/>
   </Order>
</Customer>
<Customer CustomerID="LILAS" ContactName="Carlos Gonzlez">
   <Order CustomerID="LILAS" EmployeeID="3" OrderDate="1996-08-16T00:00:00">
      <OrderDetail OrderID="10283" ProductID="72" Quantity="3"/>
   </Order>
</Customer>
</ROOT>';
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc;
GO
```

Comment: thx, one more thing how to put this all as a procedure...so that I can call it an once by passing xml itself?

Comment: Would you be passing in the xml that you are currently setting as `@doc` if yes then something like this : `CREATE PROCEDURE testproc @input XML
AS
     DECLARE @doc VARCHAR(1000);

     EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @input OUTPUT,  @doc;
GO`